# Is a countably coverable set a countable union of finitely coverable sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In a metric space, an $\epsilon$-cover of a set is a collection of balls of radius $\epsilon$ whose union includes the set. A set is finitely (respectively countably) coverable if for any $\epsilon>0$, it has a finite (respectively countable) $\epsilon$-cover.

A countable union of finitely coverable sets is countably coverable. Is every countably coverable set a countable union of finitely coverable sets?

Comment: I believe $\mathbb{R}$ gives a counterexample

Comment: @A.Ekbote I don't think so - bounded intervals are finitely coverable

Answer (score 2):

No. A counterexample is $\mathcal C([0, 1])$, the space of continuous functions on $[0, 1]$, under the $L_\infty$ norm. The entire space is countably coverable because it's separable: the polynomials with rational coefficients are a dense set. But $\mathcal C([0, 1])$ cannot be a countable union of finitely coverable sets. To prove this, we need a few lemmas.

**Lemma 1.** ([Benedek & Itai](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759190026X), Lemma 4.5) If for some $\epsilon>0$ a set $X$ in a metric space contains an infinite set of pairwise $\epsilon$-far points, it is not finitely coverable.

**Proof.** Let $(x_i)$ denote a countably infinite set of $\epsilon$-far points in $X$. By the triangle inequality, no ball of radius $\frac14\epsilon$ can contain more than one of the $x_i$. Therefore any $\frac14\epsilon$-cover for $X$ must be infinite. ∎

**Lemma 2.** In $\mathcal C([0, 1])$, any finitely coverable set is of empty interior.

**Proof.** Every open ball in $\mathcal C([0, 1])$ contains an infinite set of pairwise $\epsilon$-far points some for $\epsilon>0$. For example, take any increasing convergent sequence $x_n\to 1$ in $[0, 1]$ and define $f_n$ to be zero on $[0, x_n]$, $1$ on $[x_{n+1}, 1]$, and linear in between. Then take $m<n$. We have $x_{m+1}\leq x_n$, so $f_m(x_n)=0$ while $f_n(x_n)=1$, so $d(f_n, f_m)=1$ and the $f_i$ are pairwise $1$-far. Through scaling and translation, we can find a pairwise $\epsilon$-far sequence of points in any open ball in $\mathcal C([0, 1])$. ∎

**Lemma 3.** In any metric space, the closure of a finitely coverable set is finitely coverable.

**Proof.** Let $X$ be some finitely coverable set, and $\epsilon > 0$. We are to find a finite $\epsilon$-cover for $\overline X$. Let $c_1, ..., c_n$ be the centers of a finite $\frac\epsilon2$-cover of $X$. Let $y\in\overline X$. There is some $x\in X$ such that $d(y, x)<\frac\epsilon2$, and there is some $c_i$ such that $d(x, c_i)<\frac\epsilon 2$. Therefore $d(y, c_i)<\epsilon$ and so the balls $B(c_i, \epsilon)$ for $i=1, ..., n$ are a finite $\epsilon$-cover for $\overline X$. ∎

**Proposition.** $\mathcal C([0, 1])$ is not a countable union of finitely coverable sets.

**Proof.** Combining lemmas 2 and 3, in $\mathcal C([0, 1])$ any finitely coverable set is nowhere dense. But $\mathcal C([0, 1])$ is a complete metric space and so is a Baire space, therefore a countable union of nowhere dense sets is of empty interior. But $\mathcal C([0, 1])$ is not of empty interior. ∎